# Node.js beginner hiccups

Tags: node.js

The following lines of code is saved to hello.js

```
var hello = "Welcome to node land";

console.log('${hello}')
```

ideally running  node hello.js  should have printed

```
     Welcome to node land
```

but it just prints

```
     $hello
```

Comment: what version of node are you running?

Comment: version used is 6.9.4

Comment: Doesn't it print `${hello)` instead of `$hello` as you say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template string literals uses backticks `` ` ``, not single quotes.

```
var hello = "Welcome to node land"; 
console.log(`${hello}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the ` (backtick) character to use template literals.

```
var hello = "Welcome to node land"; 
console.log(`${hello}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no sense in doing this:

```
console.log(`${hello}`);
```

...as the other answers advocate. The only thing `` `${hello}` `` accomplishes is converting `hello` to a string, but *it's already a string*.

Just do this:

```
console.log(hello);
```

You would use a template string if you wanted to combine `hello` with other text, like this:

```
var name = "abson";
console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
```

...which would print `Hello, abson!`.